# Show/hide table range depending on selection change cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet_SelectionChange sub, that changes a range of cells when clicking on them to be either "On" or "Off":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Point_load, Line_load, Uniform_load, 
Informed_moment, Steel_bar_moment, Steel_bar_reinforcement")) Is Nothing Then

  Select Case Target.Value
  Case Range("Yes").Value
    Target.Value = Range("No").Value
    With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
    .Offset(0, 1).Select
    End With

  Case Range("No").Value
    Target.Value = Range("Yes").Value
    With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
    .Offset(0, 1).Select
    End With
  End Select
End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

These ranges should determine whether some tables should be shown or hidden. I have tried using this Worksheet_Change code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim PointLoadSection As ListObject
Set PointLoadSection = ListObjects("Point_load_section")

If Target.Address = Range("Point_load").Address Then
If Range("Point_load_shape").Value = Range("No").Value Then
    PointLoadSection.Range.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    PointLoadSection.Range.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End If
End Sub
```

However, it does not work and it is like the worksheet change does not register a change from the selection change code. I have defined the table as a ListObject. Can you help me hide/unhide the table in the example when clicking on e.g. the "Point_load" cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Change` and `SelectionChange` are two different events and respond to different actions

Comment: So the Change will not respond to the change of the Off/On cells in the SelectionChange event? Any way to get around this?

Comment: One thing is sure, that “Application.EnableEvents = False” on top of “Worksheet_SelectionChange()” event would prevent any other event reaction, hence Worksheet_Change(), too

Comment: SelectionChange will respond to any cell selection while Change will respond to actual cell's value change. As you can see, these are different events.

Comment: So would I have to place the latter code under the Worksheet_SelectionChange sub instead of under the Worksheet_Change sub?

Comment: That did the job. Thanks for pointing that out @JohnyL

Comment: You're welcome!